# JDK10: Unable to find a @SpringBootConfiguration, you need to use @ContextConfiguration or @SpringBootTest(classes=...) with your test

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, maven-surefire-plugin

I have created a simple Spring Boot application, starting of from the Spring Initializr. I added Spring Web MVC and Spring Actuator. After that, I added a HelloController which just returns a Hello message. I am using JDK 10. When I run Maven clean install, I am getting the following error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to find a @SpringBootConfiguration, you need to use @ContextConfiguration or @SpringBootTest(classes=...) with your test

When I remove my module_info.java file, everything runs ok (also if I run it with module_info.java and Maven option -DskipTests).

A sample project with the problem is available at the following location: https://github.com/mydeveloperplanet/myfabric8planet/tree/feature/surefire-problem

I already added the following [fix](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/1409) concerning the org.ow2.asm dependency.

I do not have any tests, but I am wondering why this simple example is not working when I am using Java Modules.

Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug in the Maven Surefire plugin (or in Spring)?

Answer (score 0):

You  checked the structure of your project packages . 
Why this when the package are unorganized spring can not find @Controller tag .If you want to send a print screen of the project I can have a better look .
My email mafujshikder01@gmail.com

Comment: I don't understand your request, the structure is at the GitHub url in my question. I created the project from start.spring.io and the only thing I did was to add a Controller.